# Handling multiple domains in local_name

Tags: ssl, dovecot

I have the following dovecot configuration:

```
local_name "www.example.org example.org" {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/imap.example.org.crt
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/imap.example.org.key
}
```

It doesn't match the SSL requests for www.example.org and example.org as well. It fails back to the default ssl certificate. I checked all the related logs, but nothing there.

If I change it to:

```
local_name example.org {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/imap.example.org.crt
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/imap.example.org.key
}

local_name www.example.org {
  ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/imap.example.org.crt
  ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/imap.example.org.key
}
```

It worked.

It seems that multi value configuration for local_name is not working as expected or something needs to be configured in the main configuration.

Please advise.